Relation between Laguerre function and confluent hypergeometric function
The Wikipedia article on the Rice probability distribution says that
\begin{equation}
 L_{q}(x)=L_{q}^{(0)}(x)=M(-q,1,x)=\,_{1}F_{1}(-q;1;x).
\end{equation}
where $L_q(x)$ is a Laguerre function (with $q$ not an integer).
However, while I have been able to find the above relationship for integer $q$ (see for instance, https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.6#E19 or 13.6.9 of Abramowitz and Stegun, does this relationship exist for any $q$ that is not a non-integer (or even a half-integer)? Is there any proof or reference for this?
Also, is the result generalizable to associated Laguerre functions, that is, to:
\begin{equation}
 L_{q}^{(\alpha)}(x)=L_{q}^{(0)}(x)=M(-q,1+\alpha,x)=\,_{1}F_{1}(-q;1+\alpha;x).
\end{equation}
which is the actual result in 13.6.9 of Abramowitz and Stegun or
https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.6#E19 but for integers.
Thank you in advance!
